# Netbeans 7.4 doesn't recognise PHP short tag

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7, php-shorttags

I recently updated Netbeans to 7.4 version and I actually get plenty of "errors": all the code included in short php tag is not parsed and considered almost like comment (I guess).

Does anyone knows how to fix that?

thanks

Answer (score 80, accepted):

1. **Ctrl-1** to open your **Project** window
2. *Right-click* on your *project* and *click* on **Properties**
3. Enable **Allow short tags** (<?)
4. Press **Ok**

[image: Click on Allow short tags (<?)]

Comment: I only tried to find it in the general settings panel.. That will surely fix it, thank you. Do you know if there is a similar option in the Tools->Option panel?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry; but I'd strongly suggest you not to use the short tags in order to avoid conflicts such as raw XML output :)

Comment: What's more, you should check your production environment and adapt your dev tools. allowing short tags in netbeans might lead to missunderstandings that break your production instance.

Comment: As a good practice, just don't allow (don't even turn it on in the 1st place) usage of short tags! :)

Comment: No need to blur the image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to uncheck this option.

Option >> Editor >> Uncheck Giving Space After Short Php Tag

[Settings ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVE5k.jpg)