# Netbeans 7.4 PHP highlighting doesn't work for short tags

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, highlight

In Netbeans 7.4, code like this:

```
<?php
    echo "some code here";
?>
```

is properly highlighted, however not like this:

```
<?
    echo "some code here";
?>
```

Is there somewhere I can tell Netbeans that `<?` is equivalent to `<?php` and should highlight as such?

Comment: Possibly because short open tags are no longer supported in PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker According to the [PHP Manual: Tags](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) (second paragraph), short tags are supported but discouraged since they require you to explicitly enable them in your PHP.ini via `short_open_tag=1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Netbeans 7.4 doesn't recognise PHP short tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741108/netbeans-7-4-doesnt-recognise-php-short-tag)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming 7.4 is the same as 7.3:

Right-click on your project in your Projects panel, and go to Properties. From there, tick the "Allow short tags" option and click OK.

Comment: There's an image here that shows how where to find this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741108/netbeans-7-4-doesnt-recognise-php-short-tag