# Not able to comment a short open tag in PHP using netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

Netbeans is giving a syntax error when commenting a short open tag like so

```
<?= // echo ... ?>
```

It works perfectly fine when I comment default tag

```
<?php // echo ... ?>
```

> I have short_open_tag enabled in php.ini and I checked allow short tag in netbeans project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to comment like that:

```
<?//= ... ?>
```

And no need to write echo if you're using short hand tags. As = means echo in that case.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer, Thanks for both the answer and the explanation of what = actually mean .

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl-1 to open your Project window
Right-click on your project and click on Properties
Enable Allow short tags (<?)
```

[image]

Comment: copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741108/netbeans-7-4-doesnt-recognise-php-short-tag