# Netbeans syntax checking error if HTML is within PHP IF statement

Tags: netbeans

The syntax checker won't link the if statement curly braces, this results in every file where I am doing this to show a syntax error on the last line of "Expected: End of file".

Is there a way to disable this check?

```
if(isset($successmessage)){
   ?>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><p class="mb-0"><?php echo $successMessage; ?></p></div>            
   <?
}
```

Comment: While it's good that you found an existing question that resolved your problem and took the time to post the details as an answer, it's more appropriate to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @skomisa I had no idea the problem was to do with short tags when I experienced the issue since my code only had a couple of short tags when using HTML. Perhaps best to keep it open so that the same symptoms could be searched?

Answer (score 0):

I've just worked out it's actually an issue with Netbeans having short tags disabled by default.

Either change `<?` to `<?php`

Or see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20747339/2924019