# NetBeans 15 php Short tag

Tags: php, netbeans

I am working on a legacy PHP web application that I wrote years ago, it uses the PHP short tag. I used NetBeans back then as my IDE and it worked great. Flash forward to today and I am making updates to the site. I downloaded NetBeans 15 which so far is a much prettier IDE. Problem is I can't seem to find out how to set it to recognize the PHP short tag. I see the long tag works just fine. I don't want to convert (while that would be easy enough)to long tags. Is there a way to set NetBeans 15 to recognize the PHP short tag?

I see post of doing this in oder version of NetBeans but nothing for the recent version which the UI has changed considerably.

thanks much.

Comment: Here's an answer for NetBeans 7.4 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20741108/netbeans-7-4-doesnt-recognise-php-short-tag does it work for 15?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation:
If you use Apache(2?) you can enable it in Netbeans 15 at "Customizing the Project Setup" on the source panel
https://netbeans.apache.org/kb/docs/php/project-setup.html#copy-sources

Comment: You can also enable the Apache short tags in php.ini and .htaccess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer, it was staring me right in the face when I looked in the project properties, which I know I looked before but I must of glossed over it.

[image: Netbeans Proeprties]